# Google Drive integration in React Native with continuous sync

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, google-drive-api

I am trying to build a react native app.

The purpose of the app is to sync a particular google drive folder to a local device, a predefined folder.

So, it would monitor a particular folder on google drive continuously even in the background and if there is an addition or deletion (any update) to google drive folder, it should update local files as well. If a new file, it should download that file, and if deleted some content from the drive, the same changes should reflect at the local.

I was not able to see any persistence kind of thing on google drive API documentation at
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads

Can this be achieved using google drive API or any wrapper?

In addition, if I go ahead and manually decide to download those files with the help of push notifications if the download fails in between due to network issues, does android maintains the download state and resume afterward or I'll have to manually handle these things?

*I am about to start working on the app and hence want to figure out the best available options so as not to get stuck in later stages.*

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a [watch endpoint](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch) which will automatically receive push notifications when there are changes to a user's Drive or resource.

The notification doesn't have information about what the changes are - just that some changes have been made.

You can then [retrieve the changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-changes#retrieve_changes) by polling the [`changes().list()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/list) endpoint and downloading the updated version of all changed files/folders.

Code example for retrieving the changes from this endpoint:

```
// Begin with our last saved start token for this user or the
// current token from getStartPageToken()
String pageToken = savedStartPageToken;
while (pageToken != null) {
  ChangeList changes = driveService.changes().list(pageToken)
      .execute();
  for (Change change : changes.getChanges()) {
    // Process change
    System.out.println("Change found for file: " + change.getFileId());
  }
  if (changes.getNewStartPageToken() != null) {
    // Last page, save this token for the next polling interval
    savedStartPageToken = changes.getNewStartPageToken();
  }
  pageToken = changes.getNextPageToken();
}
```